# Create a mapping based on a two dataframe Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe df where Column A presents some entities and Column B presents an index that these entities can have, In the specific example is each entity has a pair, i.e. ( a,b and c,d)

I would like to create a new column that shows instead of the index the other pair of the entity.

Initial DataFrame:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'col_A' : ['a','b','c','d'],
                  'col_B' : [1,1,2,2]});df

Index   Col A   Col B
    1      a     1
    2      b     1
    3      c     2
    4      d     2
```

and I would like to create a column C that looks like this:

```
     Index   Col A  Col B  Col_C
        1      a     1       b
        2      b     1       a
        3      c     2       d
        4      d     2       c
```

Any pythonic way for this. I would appreciate some explanation on the code.

Comment: And we'd appreciate some explanation on the question. What is this mapping you want and how is it generated?

Comment: Let me know if now the requirements are more clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I think you're good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values are unique pairs is possible create dictionary and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
a = df.groupby('col_B')['col_A'].apply(list).values.tolist()
print (a)
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

d = {}
for x in a:
    if len(x) == 2:
        i, j = x
        d[i] = j
        d[j] = i

df['Col_C'] = df['col_A'].map(d)
print (df)
  col_A  col_B Col_C
0     a      1     b
1     b      1     a
2     c      2     d
3     d      2     c
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I got a question for your code. When I change i,j = x with j,i = x AND d[i] = j, d[j] = i with d[i] = i, d[j] = j I will get a dictionary d = {a:a,b:b,....} . I would expect the same result as your code as I only  switch keys and values withing the dictionary. My understanding is that when you decalre i,j = x this takes i as the dict. key and j as the dict. value. What do I miss?

Comment: @A.Papa I think need `d[j] = j` and `d[i] = i`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you only have pairs? If yes, this is a nice hack that'll work - use `groupby` and just reverse each group:

```
df['Col_C'] = df.groupby('col_B', sort=False).col_A.apply(lambda x: x[::-1]).values
```

```
df
  col_A  col_B Col_C
0     a      1     b
1     b      1     a
2     c      2     d
3     d      2     c
```

Comment: @Coldspeed, this will work only if there are only pairs and sorted by the index. I was looking for a lookup method as the dataset is much longer and I may not have only pairs. Thanks.

Comment: @A.Papa does the index need to be sorted? False. Will it work on only pairs? False, it also works with singlets. Yes, the hack comes at the prices of flexibility.